# Using tweepy to get a keyword from a specific user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to create a listener to a very specific twitter account (mine), so I can do some automation, if I tweet something with a "special" code at the end (could be a character like "…") it will trigger an action, like adding the previous characters to a database.

So, I used Tweepy and I'm able to create the listener, filter keywords and so, but it will filter keywords from all the Tweetverse. This is my code:

```
import tweepy

cfg = { 
    "consumer_key"        : "...",
    "consumer_secret"     : "...",
    "access_token"        : "...",
    "access_token_secret" : "..." 
    }

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cfg['consumer_key'], cfg['consumer_secret'])
auth.set_access_token(cfg['access_token'], cfg['access_token_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print('error ',status)
        return False

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=myStreamListener)

myStream.filter(track=['…'])
```

It will filter all the messages containing a "…" no matter who wrote it, so I added to the last line the parameter `follow=''` like:

```
myStream.filter(follow='myTwitterName', track=['…'])
```

It always gives me a 406 error, if I use `myStream.userstream('myTwitterName')` it will give me, not just the Tweets I write, but also my whole timeline.

So, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I just find my first error. I was using user's screen name, not Twitter ID. Now I got rid of the 406 error, but still doesn't work. I placed the Twitter ID in the follow parameter, but does absolutely nothing. I tried both, with my account and with an account that is too "live", like CNN (ID = 759251), I see new tweets coming in my browser, but nothing on the listener.

If you're interested on knowing your own Twitter ID, I used this service: http://gettwitterid.com/

Comment: According to [InMotionHosting](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/error-numbers/406-error), "In regards to a site on your hosting account, the cause of the 406 error is usually due to a mod_security rule on the server. Mod_security is a security module in the Apache web server that is enabled by default on all hosting accounts. If a site, page, or function violates one of these rules, server may send the 406 Not Acceptable error."

Comment: According to Twitter API, 406 means "Not Acceptable, Returned when an invalid format is specified in the request.", so I really have no idea what's going on. As I said, the listener works perfectly when I don't try to filter for a specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved. It was working from the very beggining, I made two mistakes:

- To solve the 406 error all it has to be done, is to use Twitter id instead of Twitter name.
- The listener was apparently doing nothing, because I was sending "big" tweets, that is, tweets longer than 140 chars. In this case, you shouldn't use `status.text`, but `status.extended_tweet['full_text']`
- You must check for the existance of the `extended_tweet`, if it is not in the status received, then you should use the `text`

Comment: How do you avoid to get tweets that tag/mention the user? Im getting all the tweets where other people tag the user im targetting. Thanks!